# get variable data from json array string

Tags: javascript, json

json string

```
var jsonString ='[
{`"id":1`,"parentId":"0","name":"Mc Donald","value":{"name":"Mc Donald","device_id":null,"loc_det_id":"1"}},
{"id":"2","parentId":"1","name":"All Regions","value":{"name":"All Regions","isleaf":false,"device_id":null,"loc_det_id":"2"}},
{"id":"5","parentId":"2","name":"West","value":{"name":"West","isleaf":false,"device_id":null,"loc_det_id":"5"}},
{"id":"7","parentId":"5","name":"Mumbai","value":{"name":"Mumbai","isleaf":false,"device_id":null,"loc_det_id":"7"}}
]'
```

`jsonString[0].id`, this will give me the `id` as `1`

But to get value of `parentId` or `name` then?

Comment: Can't you do this: `jsonString[0].parentId`.

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) which will cast your string to a valid JSON object.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
jsonData[0].id
jsonData[0].name
jsonData[0].parentId
```

or

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
jsonData[0]['id']
jsonData[0]['name']
jsonData[0]['parentId']
```

Comment: Question was how to get parentId or name, but not id.